# Why does MySQL not use indexes for this select query?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-indexes

Why does this query not use indexes here? The table uses the InnoDB engine.

```
explain SELECT null as id,
    ->  up_time,
    ->  reg_date,
    ->  refer,
    ->  MAX(IFNULL(visits_count,0)) as visits_count,
    ->  MAX(IFNULL(register_count,0)) as register_count,
    ->  MAX(IFNULL(players_count,0)) as players_count,
    ->  MAX(IFNULL(activity_count,0)) as activity_count,
    ->  MAX(IFNULL(payment_users_count,0)) as payment_users_count,
    ->  MAX(IFNULL(payment_count,0)) as payment_count,
    ->  MAX(IFNULL(payment_sum,0)) as payment_sum FROM stats_refers
    ->
    ->  WHERE
    ->
    ->  stats_refers.reg_date < 1435006800
    ->  AND stats_refers.up_time < 1435006800
    ->
    ->  GROUP BY stats_refers.refer, stats_refers.reg_date;
```

And the explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys              | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stats_refers | ALL  | reg_date,stat,up_reg_index | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2983126 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+----------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

And the keys that can be used:

```
+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| stats_refers |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | id          | A         |     2983126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stats_refers |          0 | reg_date     |            1 | reg_date    | A         |       13317 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stats_refers |          0 | reg_date     |            2 | up_time     | A         |     1491563 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stats_refers |          0 | reg_date     |            3 | refer       | A         |     2983126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stats_refers |          1 | stat         |            1 | reg_date    | A         |       15142 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stats_refers |          1 | stat         |            2 | refer       | A         |       28683 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stats_refers |          1 | refer_uptime |            1 | refer       | A         |        2307 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stats_refers |          1 | refer_uptime |            2 | up_time     | A         |     1491563 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stats_refers |          1 | up_reg_index |            1 | reg_date    | A         |        2314 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stats_refers |          1 | up_reg_index |            2 | up_time     | A         |     1491563 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

And here is the table description:

```
CREATE TABLE `stats_refers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reg_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `up_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `refer` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `visits_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `register_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `players_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `activity_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `payment_users_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `payment_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `payment_sum` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `reg_date` (`reg_date`,`up_time`,`refer`),
  KEY `stat` (`reg_date`,`refer`),
  KEY `refer_uptime` (`refer`,`up_time`),
  KEY `up_reg_index` (`reg_date`,`up_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4136504 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys                     | key         | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stats_refers | index | reg_date,up_time,reg,search_index | group_index | 54      | NULL | 3011896 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-----------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: can or can't use indexes?...

Comment: can't, sorry, ill fix it

Comment: no worries. Just wanted to clarify. Is the `id` column unique? possibly `auto_increment`ing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the data types of the fields?

Comment: Yep, id is primary unique key

Comment: I'v added table decr

Answer (score 2):

The compound index `stat`, which I assume was created for use for this grouping operation, is in the reverse order for doing the grouping operation that you are trying to perform.  To have an index available for this grouping operation, you would need to do one of the following:

- reverse the column order on the `stat` index
- add an individual index on `refer`
- add another compound index on `refer`, `reg_date`

What decision you make would ultimately need to consider other query operations on the table.

You may want to think more broadly about your index usage here.  While using compound indexes can improve  performance vs. using individual indexes for each field that might need to be used across the range of queries on the table, in your case, you are replicating indexes on the same fields in different combinations within your table description.  Without understanding all query use cases you might have it would be hard to look at overall indexing recommendations, but I just wanted to point out that you may want to think about this.

For example, there would be no apparent need at all for your `up_reg_index` as that indexing is already covered by the `reg_date` unique index.  You might be best served with a set of indexes like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `regdate_uptime_refer` (`reg_date`,`up_time`,`refer`),
KEY `reg_date` (`reg_date`),
KEY `refer` (`refer`),
KEY `up_time` (`up_time`),
```

This would certainly require less space for your indexes than what you currently have and would allow for more flexibility in how to filter/join/group on these columns, but don't take this as a firm recommendation.  Test the performance of different indexing scenarios against your different query scenarios (particularly insert performance if that is a use case).

Comment: +1 for your explanation and recommendations, however, I have one query. Why does it can't user 'refer' part of multi column index 'refer_uptime'? I mean what benefit does adding individual index on 'refer' column gives over already existing a multi column index with 'refer' as first column?

Comment: @sactiw  Check out the GROUP BY optimizatoin documentation from MySQL - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html   Look specifically at the 2nd bullet point under "Loose Index Scan".  That specifically discusses this condition.  Also look at last example in that section of queries that could not use Loose Index Scan.  You are not applying a constant in WHERE clause for `uptime` (you are specifying a range) so the index won't be used.  You also don't meet conditions for "Tight Index Scan".

Comment: So, i'v created single indexes on up_time,refer and reg_time and also created index ( refer + reg_date) for group by operation. Now i can see group_by key in query explain, but unfortunately it saves me only 5 seconds (65 instead of 70 ) . Do you have more ideas how i can optimize it?

Comment: @Pavel Do you mean the query itself takes 65 seconds or running the query and downloading the result set takes 65 seconds?

Comment: @MikeBrant The query itselft takes 60 seconds. and a few seconds to download all 11 200 rows.

Comment: @Pavel  It is really hard to say without getting a new explain. One other thing that I didn't think about before was that since your aggregation operations (`MAX()`) are happening against a calculated value, this may be causing problems.  Why not just remove the checks for NULL altogether as NULL values would just be ignored by `MAX()` anyway.

Comment: I'v removed IF (the table have restriction for null column values anyway, and added the new explain. But still cant get the reason why this query lasts 60+ seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(refer, reg_date)
```

in *that* order *might* get the optimizer to use that for the `GROUP BY`.

```
INDEX(up_time)
```

*might* be useful for the part of the `WHERE` that references `up_time`.

```
    reg_date < 1435006800
AND up_time  < 1435006800
```

The optimizer will *think about* using `INDEX(reg_date, ...)` *or* `INDEX(up_time, ...)`, but only if the 'range' is less than, say, 20% of the table.  It is very unlikely to try to use two separate indexes and do a "index merge".

Because of the "ranges" in the `WHERE`, it is not possible to have an index that handles both the `WHERE` and the `ORDER BY`.

No other indexes are useful for that query.

This 20% is imprecise.  It exists because if too much of the table needs to be looked at, it is actually faster to do a table scan than to use the index.

You are selecting `up_time`, but not grouping by it.  That's naughty.  The query can deliver whatever `up_time` it feels like.

Why have an `id`, since you have a `UNIQUE` key that could be the `PRIMARY KEY`?  I ask because the "clustering" of the PK could lead to this being the best option:

```
PRIMARY KEY(refer, reg_date, uptime)
```

(Of course, changing just that might mess up other queries.)